Book on Mathematical Problem-Solving Techniques
I'm looking for books that present, discuss, and provide accessible examples of mathematical problem-solving techniques, such as:

Dividing complex problems into smaller parts (Decomposition),
Thinking backward,
Recursion,
Iteration,
Experimentation and trial and error,
Pattern recognition,
Algebraic thinking,
Visualization,
Logical reasoning,
Use of invariants,
Exhaustive search,
Mathematical modeling,
Proof by contradiction,
Proof by induction,
Case analysis,
Probabilistic thinking,
Heuristics,
Reasoning by simulation,
Use of symmetry,
Problem reformulation.

extra though: I'm wondering if there are problems from the International Mathematical Kangaroo Competition that demonstrate the application of these techniques. The solutions to these competition problems could serve as practical examples.

I upvoted, as I think is a reasonable question. I don't get the two downvotes.


How to Solve Mathematical Problems by Wickelgreen.

https://www.amazon.com/Solve-Mathematical-Problems-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486284336
(not promotional)
I have this book and have skimmed it.  Seems to be thoughtfully intentioned.  Covers several of your named methods.  And does so in the context of puzzle problems (albeit maybe a bit easier than your target).  Still, decent fit.  Since it's Dover, it's cheap.

You should check out Polya's Solve It (high school math level) and his two volume set, Induction and Analogy in Mathematics (mostly uses number theory problems to illustrate).  If price is an issue or not sure you will like them, than get library copies.

I suspect Google search or Amazon book search would readily come up with other candidates.

I would also consider the "two book" solution.  I.e. One book that is more on methods (but perhaps not competition problems) and another that is more a set of competition problems/hints/solutions.  Perhaps it is an educational exercise to see if you can identify strategies (from the strategies book) used in the competition drill problem book.  I.e. challenging yourself to make the translation.  [I would also note that not all competition problems are a simple matter of using a method.  Partial overlap Venn diagram, if you get me.]



A friend of mine recommended the following book:
Problem-Solving Through Problems by Loren C. Larson (not a promotional reference): https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5498-0
